# Elasticsearch: Query the most recent that doesn't contain the field 'X'

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following search query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "testlib"
    }
  }
}
```

When I do this query I get the three results below. What I want to do now is only return one result: the newest `@timestamp` that doesn't contain `version_pre`. So in this case, only return `AV6qvDXDyHw9vNh6Wlpl`.

```
[
    {
        "_index": "testsoftware",
        "_type": "software",
        "_id": "AV6qvDXDyHw9vNh6Wlpl",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
            "@timestamp": "2017-09-21T11:02:15-04:00",
            "name": "testlib",
            "version_major": 1,
            "version_minor": 0,
            "version_patch": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "testsoftware",
        "_type": "software",
        "_id": "AV6qvDF5MtcMTuGknsVs",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
            "@timestamp": "2017-09-20T17:21:35-04:00",
            "name": "testlib",
            "version_major": 1,
            "version_minor": 0,
            "version_patch": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "testsoftware",
        "_type": "software",
        "_id": "AV6qvDnVyHw9vNh6Wlpn",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
            "@timestamp": "2017-09-22T13:56:55-04:00",
            "name": "testlib",
            "version_major": 1,
            "version_minor": 0,
            "version_patch": 2,
            "version_pre": 0
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sort (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-exists-query.html:

```
{
"size" : 1,
"sort" : [{ "@timestamp" : {"order" : "asc"}}],
"query" : {
"bool": {
    "must_not": {
        "exists": {
            "field": "version_pre"
        }
    }
}
```

Or even, via query string:

```
/_search?sort=@timestamp:desc&size=1&q=_missing_:version_pre
```

Comment: In my case I need to match the `name` field also because the match has to be within the name that is being queried. So I just added a `should` to the `bool`